# An additional page is created at the end of my document. How to remove it?

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, page

Unfortunately, a second page is automatically generated. This page should be the last page of the document and the back cover of the two-sided book, whith no page number, header and footer.

```
 \documentclass
[paper=a4,      % A4
twoside=off,     % nicht doppelseitig setzen
DIV=13,         % Vordefinierte Seitenränder (15=min, 0=max)
fontsize=12pt,  % default font size
BCOR=15.0mm,    % zusätzlicher Binderand, 15 ~ 0
parskip=half,   % Absatzabstandsstyle
cleardoublepage=empty] % nur Seitenzahlen auf Korrekturseiten
{scrbook} 


% Font wählen, Computer Modern ist KEIN geeigneter Druckfont!
\usepackage{arial}
\usepackage{calligra}


 % Im folgenden an Paketen auswählen, was man braucht
 \usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage{amsthm}
 \usepackage{amssymb}

 %Grafiken
  \usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
 \usepackage{tikz}

 \usepackage{bbm}

 \usepackage{scrpage2}
 %Zitate
 \usepackage{cite}
%Bildunterschriften
 \usepackage[bf, format=plain]{caption}

%Für textumflossene Bilder
\usepackage{wrapfig}

%Was noch zu machen ist
\usepackage{todonotes}
%Für die Links vom Inhaltsverzeichnis aus
\usepackage{hyperref}
 %Wrapfigures abbrechen
 %\usepackage{placeins}
%Wrapfigures neues Paket
 \usepackage{float} 
   %Kets und Bras...
 \usepackage{braket}
 %Tabelle in Querformat
 \usepackage{lscape}
 %Damit µ aufrecht bleibt
  \usepackage{textcomp}
 \usepackage{mathcomp}
%Für Zeilenumbruch in Tabellenzellen
 \usepackage{multirow}
%Für Trennlinien in Tabellen
\usepackage{booktabs}
%Damit Einheiten nicht kursiv sind
\usepackage{siunitx}
%Für Farben
\usepackage{color}
%\usepackage{subfigure}
%\usepackage{multirow}
%\usepackage{multicol}
%\usepackage{rotating}
%\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{url}
%\usepackage{nat}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage{indentfirst} % richtiges Einrücken der Kapitel
 \usepackage{url}
  \usepackage{listings}
    \lstset{basicstyle=\scriptsize,
        xleftmargin=10mm,
        numbers=left, numberstyle=\tiny, stepnumber=2,
        frame=single, framexleftmargin=8mm, framexbottommargin=5mm,
        captionpos=b,
        aboveskip=10mm, belowskip=10mm}
   \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         
   \usepackage{titlesec}

      \titleformat*{\section}{\large\bfseries}
     \titleformat*{\subsection}{\normalfont\bfseries}
        \titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\normalfont\bfseries}
         \setkomafont{chapterprefix}{\normalsize\sffamily\b fseries}
          \addtokomafont{chapter}{\rmfamily\bfseries}

         %to add bibliography in the contents
        \usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}

        %list of abbreviations
             \usepackage{nomencl}
        \makenomenclature

  %equation chem
  \usepackage{chemmacros}

  %vector symbol in equations
  \usepackage{esvect}

 \usepackage{afterpage}

  %tables
  \usepackage{array}
  \newcolumntype{x}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
 \usepackage{tabularx}
  \renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
  \newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
 \newlength\lengtha \setlength\lengtha{3mm} 
\newlength\lengthb \setlength\lengthb{7mm}
 \newlength\lengthc \setlength\lengthc{1.5mm} 
 \newlength\lengthd \setlength\lengthd{3mm}

%force the figures to be placed in the section or subsection of choice
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\let\Oldsection\section
\renewcommand{\section}{\FloatBarrier\Oldsection}
\let\Oldsubsection\subsection
\renewcommand{\subsection}{\FloatBarrier\Oldsubsection}
\let\Oldsubsubsection\subsubsection
\renewcommand{\subsubsection}{\FloatBarrier\Oldsubsubsection}

 %footnotes table
\usepackage{booktabs,caption,fixltx2e}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}

 % position caption table
\usepackage{floatrow}
\floatsetup[table]{capposition=top}

\usepackage[titletoc,page]{appendix}

%less spacing table of content
\usepackage{tocloft}



\usepackage{cleveref}

\usepackage{parskip}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{ragged2e}


\usepackage{lipsum,afterpage}



\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@endpart{\vfil
          \if@twoside
            \null
            \thispagestyle{empty}%
            \newpage
          \fi
          \if@tempswa
            \twocolumn
          \fi}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\sloppy
\frontmatter


\label{mathrefs}




     \mainmatter
     \label{mathrefs}

    \begin{titlepage}
     \thispagestyle{empty}
    \vspace*{18cm}
 Name A. Surname\\
    \vskip 2mm
 University\\
Institut \\
Wolfgang-Gaede-Stra{\ss}e 1 \\
D-74131 City\\
research group\\
website\\
 \end{titlepage}



\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `\vspace*{\fill}` instead of `\vspace*{18cm}` at the beginning of the `titlepage` environment. The 18cm are to high and so the (unneeded?) `\\` results in a page break.

```
\documentclass
[paper=a4,      % A4
twoside=off,    % nicht doppelseitig setzen
DIV=13,         % Vordefinierte Seitenränder (15=min, 0=max)
fontsize=12pt,  % default font size
BCOR=15.0mm,    % zusätzlicher Binderand, 15 ~ 0
parskip=half,   % Absatzabstandsstyle
cleardoublepage=empty] % nur Seitenzahlen auf Korrekturseiten
{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\vspace*{\fill}
Name A. Surname\\[2mm]
University\\
Institut \\
Wolfgang-Gaede-Straße 1 \\
D-74131 City\\
research group\\
website
\vspace*{\baselineskip}% if there should be an empty line at the text bottom
\end{titlepage}
%\null\thispagestyle{empty}% only if there is an empty page needed
\end{document}
```

---

Additional remarks:

Do **not** use packages like `titlesec`, `tocloft`, `parskip`, `indentfirst`, `tocbibind` ... together with a KOMA-Script class. You can get the same or a similar result using KOMA-Script commands.

Normally package `hyperref` should be loaded as the last one. One exception is package `cleveref`.

Package `scrpage2` is deprecated since 2014. Use its successor `scrlayer-scrpage`